# Charles Web Debugging Proxy rewrite not working

Tags: java, regex, expression, charles-proxy

Here is the response:

```
{"xxx", "yyy", "zzz":"abc,def"}
```

(abc,def is not a constant string, every time it will change.)

For example, I want to rewrite "abc,def" so I use this Regex expression `"zzz":"(*)+"` and rewrite as `"zzz":"rewrote!"`, but I got fail, Charles won't regex it, I think the Regex expression may wrong. If I want to rewrite it, what should be put in the Regex expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your example `"zzz":"(*)+"`, here `(*)+` doesn't mean anything to your example.

You can replace it with `"[^"]+"` to match anything between quotes except the quote itself. For example:

`"zzz":"[^"]+"`

`+` for at least a character in it. If you replace `+` with `*` it will be zero or more character.